# How to find floor on big floating point numbers?

Tags: python, floor

How could I correctly find `floor(a*n)` in python where `n` is a very large  floating point number?

I tried it using `Decimal` module but

```
Deciaml(1.1) * Decimal(123456789123456789123456789)
```

It is not giving right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a float to construct a Decimal, the precision has already been lost.  Initialize it with a string:

```
>>> Decimal(1.1) * Decimal(123456789123456789123456789)
Decimal('135802468035802479000968054.4')
>>> Decimal('1.1') * Decimal(123456789123456789123456789)
Decimal('135802468035802468035802467.9')
```